# ImportError: cannot import name 'legacy_round' from 'textstat.textstat'

Tags: python, nlp, importerror, readability

I am trying to import `legacy_round` from `textstat` as follows:

`from textstat.textstat import textstatistics,legacy_round`

But I get following error:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'legacy_round' from 'textstat.textstat'`

Any idea how can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

legacy_round was removed from recent version and it is possible you are using an older version.

You could try downgrading the textstat package to a version that includes it:

```
pip install textstat==0.6.2
```

Or you can use the round function from the Python standard library instead of legacy_round:

```
from textstat.textstat import textstatistics
import math


flesch_reading_ease = textstatistics().flesch_reading_ease(text)
flesch_reading_ease_rounded = math.floor(flesch_reading_ease + 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to @alxwrd in ([*#186*](https://github.com/textstat/textstat/issues/186)), you need to use [`_legacy_round`](https://github.com/textstat/textstat/blob/9bf37414407bcaaa45c498478ee383c8738e5d0c/textstat/textstat.py#L112) instead of `legacy_round`.

```
from textstat.textstat import textstatistics

#add these two lines
from textstat import textstat
legacy_round = textstat._legacy_round
```